# HTML-modifying JavaScript Code says that my HTML Element is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently trying to get a simple Category System to work.
To do so, I've created a tiny Category "class" which fits my needs:

```
var categories = [];
function Category (id, name, ownedBy){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.ownedBy = ownedBy;
    categories[id] = this;
}
```

id is, well, the ID of the Category. It's name is only used for display purposed. And "ownedBy" is the ID of the super-category, or "none" if it hasn't one.

After filling my categories-array, I iterate over it and call a function of mine to add the categories to my HTML-Code:

```
function addHTMLCategory(catID){
    var cat = categories[catID]; //Get the Category-"Object"
    if(!cat) return;             //If it doesn't exist, do nothing.

    if(cat.ownedBy != "none"){   //If the category has a supercategory,
        addHTMLCategory(cat.ownedBy); //Add it to the HTML first.
    }
    if(document.getElementById("cat"+catID)) return; //And if it already exists, dont add it again.

    //ERROR-PART: If a category has a superclass, get the superclass element.
    var contentElement = document.getElementById(cat.ownedBy=="none"?"categories":"cat"+cat.ownedBy);
    var li = document.createElement("div");
    li.id = "cat"+catID;
    li.className = "category";
    li.innerText = cat.name;
    contentElement.appendChild(li);
}
```

Initial HTML:

```
<div id="categories"></div>
```

This function checks if the Category has a Super-Category, and if yes, it adds this one first: I did this to avoid that the element where the category should be added to doesn't exist.

Unfortunately, exactly this happens: When a Category has a super-category, the "contentElement" variable is null. Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: if contentElement == null, then "cat"+cat.ownedBy is not existing in your DOM

Comment: It might be possible to answer the question in its current state, but it would be easier if perhaps you could add the `li ...element creation...` code, as well as your initial HTML, and your sequence of add events. As John Smith pointed out, something isn't existing in your DOM but we don't see how your DOM starts or how it is set. or make a fiddle/add a code widget?

Comment: @johnSmith I know, but I can't understand why it is null since I implemented that "cat.ownedBy != "none"" check..

Comment: well a simple `console.log(cat.ownedBy)` will bring some light

Comment: And you have made sure somehow, that the elements for super-categories are created before the ones for “normal” categories?

Comment: @johnSmith I already added so many debug-messages and deleted them because I lost my mind... But your comment gave me an idea; I'm going to try it out right now and update this post afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, with the "if(cat.ownedBy != "none")addHTMLCategory(cat.ownedBy);".

Comment: @johnSmith Works now, thanks! My problem was that ownedBy actually was the name of the category, and not it's ID.

Comment: as i said, a simple console.log() will always bring light, this is called debugging

Comment: You didn't include the code that creates Category objects.

Comment: If `cat.ownedBy` is not a valid index into categories, the recursion will obtain undefined for `categories[catId]` and simply return. BTW, you make sure catId is a number if not "none".

Comment: @Robinlikethebird Yep, this was exactly my problem =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the ownedBy variable of Category was set to the name of the super-category, instead of its ID (In another part of the code which I thought was irrelevant)

Comment: Yep, that's what I speculated in my last comment.